# Дано три числа, если сумма их положительная, изменить второе число на противоположное

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Дано три числа, если сумма их положительная, изменить второе число на противоположное.

Код неправильно работает. Препод сказала, что "естественно, он будет неправильно работать". Даже показала, что проблема во второй части кода, но не сказала какая. Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться.

```Assembler
.586
.model flat,C
Option Casemap: None
.Data
a dd 1
b dd 2
c1 dd 3
d dd 0
.Data?
x   dd ?
.Code
start:   
mov  EAX,a
add  EAX,b
add  EAX,c1
mov  EBX,d
cmp  EAX,EBX
jl   m1
  jmp finish
  nop    
m1:
  not b
  nop
finish:  
 end start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там стоит not b, not инвертирует биты, а не число, тут нужно использовать neg. Еще для сравнения с нулем лучше использовать cmp eax, 0, jl нужно заменить на jg. А еще там неиспользуемая переменная и ненужные nopы. Советую почитать [мануал Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4), там подробно описана работа каждой инструкции.

Comment: Совет почитать мануал Intel - это примерно как совет только начавшему изучать английский почитать англорусский словарь - там подробно описано каждое слово. Это к тому, что мануалы Intel не очень подходят как учебник ассемблера x86, это скорее справочник, в который иногда нужно заглядывать (как в словарь - если следовать аналогии с иностранным языком).

Comment: @insolor это да, но здесь проблема заключалась как раз в незнании того, как работают инструкции.

Comment: Я поменяла команду not на neg, убрала ненужную переменную и nopы, но программа все равно не работает. 
Возможно, что я что-то не так поняла или не так сделала.

Comment: @JulienJackson да, еще jl выполняет переход если eax < 0, нужно заменить на jg

Comment: @СергейКривенко да, действительно, теперь все правильно. Спасибо